# Cant seem to add percentages to get the right value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner to jQuery and can't seem to figure this out
Why can't i use

```
var main = $('#content');
main.css("width","+=15%");
```

The original `width: 70%;`
after the call `width: 622.6%;`

I need it to be `width: 85%;`

What might be the error, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: i need it to 85%

Comment: You'll have to extract the current width and remove the percentage, then sum with the extra percentage.

Comment: @gundergobi it looks like you just need to do this then: `main.css("width","85%");`

Comment: @Phiter is that the only way?. Guys i need it to be dynamic. Because width might change from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `main.css('width')` will give the value in pixels.

But you can make a calculation based on the parents width:

```
var main = $('#content');
var porcentage = main.width() / main.parent().width() * 100;
porcentage = Math.ceil(porcentage);
porcentage += 15;
main.css('width', porcentage+'%');
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/op393vx7/8/)